# Отправить input в post и get

Tags: javascript, jquery

Чтобы оправить форму в get и post я использую такую форму:

```
<form name="send" action="/example.php?id=1" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <p> <b>Удалить куки: </b><input type="checkbox" name="delete_cookie" value="1"> </p>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="3">
    <input type="submit"  value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Мне нужно с помощью jQuery некоторые `input` например с `class="get-key"`, отправить с помощью `get`.
То есть что делаю, создаю input с классом.
Дальше все значения с помощью `.each` я собираюсь в массив допустим id и value.
Проблема лишь в том что как мне с помощью jQuery все id и value которые я собрал из `input`'ов поместить в `action="example.php?id=val....&id[n]=val[n]`.

Answer (score 1):

Для отправки `get` запроса в jQuery существует [одноимённый метод](http://jquery-docs.ru/Ajax/jQuery.get/).
Например:

```
$.get(adress);
```

Однако в случае jQuery лучше всего не вставлять переменные напрямую в адресную строку, а формировать данные в формате JSON или XML

Answer (score 0):

Как Вы уже написали: *создаю `input` с классом `class="get-key"`. Дальше, все значения с помощью `.each` собираю в массив допустим `id` и `value`.* После этого, подготовленные данные в виде массива преобразуем в `JavaScript` с помощью [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) в строку `JSON`:

```
data = JSON.stringify(dataArray); // dataArray - подготовленные данные
```

После того, как данные подготовлены, можно осуществить отправку через [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://jquery-docs.ru/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax( { // ajax запрос
  type: "GET", // с помощью get
  url: 'example.php', // по адресу
  data: { array: data }, // отправляемые данные 
  success: function(response) { // в случае успеха
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(response) { // в случае провала
    console.log(response);
  },
});
```

[`jQuery.ajax()`](https://jquery-docs.ru/jQuery.ajax/) - выполняет асинхронный `HTTP(Ajax)`-запрос. Также, можно использовать [`jQuery.get()`](https://jquery-docs.ru/jQuery.get/) для загрузки данных с сервера при помощи `HTTP-GET` запроса.

Comment: Собственно, а где в ссылках перечисленных вами написано что $.get используется лишь для загрузки данных с сервера? 
По мне так все 3 функции для работы с Ajax это всего лишь различные обертки под XMLHttpRequest и по сути не так важно $.get $.post если конечно не углубляться в разницу между методами

Comment: @ДмитрийПриходченко, автор вопроса указал: *отправить с помощью `get`*. По поводу Вашего вопроса, я не писал **лишь**. Откройте ссылку: [jQuery.get()](https://jquery-docs.ru/jQuery.get/) и найдите там текст: *Загружает данные с сервера при помощи HTTP GET запроса*. Откройте ссылку: [jQuery.ajax()](https://jquery-docs.ru/jQuery.ajax/) и найдите там текст: *Выполняет асинхронный HTTP (Ajax) запрос*. Там все это есть. Ссылки я привел не просто так, а для изучения и подтверждения написанного мной.